# How to set wallpaper Image permently? (android, eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'am making an android wallpaper app but whenever I restart my phone the wallpaper zooms so I tried using BootReciever but I failed nothing different has happened the wallpaper stills zoom after restarting the phone.

So here is my MainActivity java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public static final String KEY = "wallpaperapp";
          private SharedPreferences sharedPreference;
          private int retrievedImageID;

static int tophone;
ImageView display;
public static Integer[] tophone2 = {
    R.drawable.iv1,R.drawable.iv2,R.drawable.iv3,R.drawable.iv4,};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tophone = R.drawable.iv1;
    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IView);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv4);
    Button setWp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setWp);

    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.iv1_s).into(image1);
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.iv2_s).into(image2);
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.iv3_s).into(image3);
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.iv4_s).into(image4);



    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);
    image3.setOnClickListener(this);
    image4.setOnClickListener(this);
    setWp.setOnClickListener(this);

    sharedPreference = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    changeWallpaper();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.iv1:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv1);
        tophone = R.drawable.iv1;
        break;
    case R.id.iv2:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv2);
        tophone = R.drawable.iv2;
        break;
    case R.id.iv3:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv3);
        tophone = R.drawable.iv3;
        break;
    case R.id.iv4:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv4);
        tophone = R.drawable.iv4;
        break;
    case R.id.setWp:
        Toast WpSet = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), tophone);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this); 
        wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
        try {
          wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
          } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WpSet.show();
        break;

}
    sharedPreference.edit().putInt(KEY, v.getId()).commit();



}
public void changeWallpaper(){
       int someDefaultValue = R.id.iv1;
       retrievedImageID = sharedPreference.getInt(KEY, someDefaultValue);
       display.setImageResource(retrievedImageID);
}
}
```

and here is my BootReciever java:

```
 public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 private static final String TAG="BootReceiver";

@Override public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
try{
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), MainActivity.tophone);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context); 
        wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
        try {
          wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
          } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
 }
}
}
```

If you know how to solve this please tell me, and please try to add an example using my code, or tell me how the final code should like, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean the wallpaper zooms? Is it bigger or zoomed in, comparing to the initial state?

Comment: it usually fits the screen perfectly but then it get zoomed in after restarting the phone @joao2fast4u

Comment: for example if the wallpaper contains the word "WALLPAPER" the entire word will be shown but after restating the device only "LPAP" will be shown but the letters will become really big @joao2fast4u

Comment: Are you applying some scale effect on your Bitmap. Like cropping or something?

Comment: yes i'am scaling it to fit the screen